# Can you access a private variable of an instance if it is in the same class? (copyOf)

Tags: java, scope, private

As an example,

```
public class SwapNumbers {

private int aNumber = 0; ///////////////////////////////////

    public SwapNumbers(){

    }

    public void changeNumber(int changed){
    aNumber = changed;

    }
    public void swap(SwapNumbers otherNumber){ ///////////

    aNumber = otherNumber.aNumber; //Can we access aNumber?
    }


}
```

would the swap in this work? My first instinct was that it would not work because it is trying to access a private value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. making a member `private` means it is available to the current class along with any of its inner-classes, subject to static qualifiers.

Package-private (or the default, without any access modifiers) means it is available to any class in the same package.

the `public` modifier makes it available to any class in any package anywhere. Be careful with these :)

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought that it was limited to the current class AND the current instance.  I will accept this answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are within the same class, you will have no problems accessing any variables within the class--private, protected, or public.

You will only be unable to access private variables from outside

```
public class SwapNumber {
...
}
```